# Read and extract huge zip file from AWS S3 with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on data management application where client can upload `zip file(approx 250 MB)` with multiple `text files(approx 1500 MB)` on `AWS S3`.

But due to limited memory of `aws lamda` (max 1536MB size) I am able to extract zip file of (50 MB) with extracted files of (500 MB).

Since I need to add some validation on extracted files while extracting and after that I have to store all contents of file in to database.

For now I am storing the content of files in `aws-lambda tmp location` which also has limitation of max 500MB can use.

any streaming concept which can help to do my above task with validation will be helpful for me.

I can go with `EC2, ECS` but right now I want to do with only `AWS-Lambda`.

With this code I am extracting and uploading the zip files to another `S3` bucket.

Any other concept like streaming will be helpful for me as I am not much familiar with streaming concept I am putting here to get some idea to resolve my issue.

```
s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
        var message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.`;
        console.log(message);
        //  callback(message);
    } else {
        console.log('Started to buffer data');
        JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body).then(function(zip) {
            fs.writeFile('temp/hello.txt', 'New file added for testing');
            async.each(zip.files, function(item, cb1) {
                if (!item.dir && item.name.includes('nightly')) {
                    zip.file(item.name).async("text").then(function(content) {
                        fs.writeFile('temp/' + item.name.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''), content, function(err) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            cb1();
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    cb1();
                }
            }, function(err, result) {
                var zipObj = new JSZip();
                fs.readdir('./temp', function(err, files) {
                    console.log(files);
                    async.each(files, function(file, cb2) {
                        fs.readFile('./temp/' + file, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
                            if (err) {
                                return err;
                            }
                            zipObj.file(file, content);
                            cb2();
                        });
                    }, function(err) {
                        zipObj.generateAsync({
                                type: "nodebuffer"
                            })
                            .then(function(content) {
                                console.log(content);
                                deleteFiles(['./temp/*'], function(err, paths) {
                                    console.log('Deleted files/folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
                                });

                                s3.putObject({
                                    Bucket: 'abtempb',
                                    Key: 'temp/records.zip',
                                    Body: content
                                }, function(err, result) {
                                    if (result && result.ETag) {
                                        console.log('uploaded file: ', result.ETag);
                                    }
                                    console.log('Error ', err);
                                });
                            });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

***Thank You***

Comment: Use streaming extraction. This will limit the amount of memory required to perform the extraction.

Comment: Can you provide some chunk of code or any reference to get streaming concept?

Comment: Download the file from S3 to local filesystem and then use nodejs streaming zip module, something like https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip

Comment: You might also face lambda timeout (15min - used to be 5min) over large files. Would a programmatically generated s3-presigned url (or with cloudfront if you do not want to expose s3 to public) work for your case? then you would not have to be the middle man for transferring the data.

Comment: can it be a gzip file? or zip only?

Answer (score -1):

You can now mount EFS volumes on Lambda. Details can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/).